# : Argument of type 'ItmesModel[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, group-by, pipe, grouping

I have this JSON, and I want to group by category items.

```
 data: any[] = [
    {
      id:1,
      name: 'test',
      items: [
        {
          itemNumber: "0002",
          itemId: "22222",
          category: 'A'
        },
        {
          itemNumber: "0012",
          itemId: "666666",
          category: 'A'
        },
         {
          itemNumber: "0502",
          itemId: "555",
          category: 'B'
        }
      ]
    },
           {
      id:2,
      name: 'test 2',
      items: [
        {
          itemNumber: "08802",
          itemId: "88888",
          category: 'C'
        },
        {
          itemNumber: "7578",
          itemId: "5785785",
          category: 'C'
        },
         {
          itemNumber: "06986802",
          itemId: "2424",
          category: 'C'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

In .html I have 2 *ngFor

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let d of data; index as i">
     {{d.name}}
     ......
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of d?.items | groupBy: 'category'; index as j">
                <div class="label-view">
                  {{item.category}}
                </div>
                <div class="label-view">
                  {{item.itemNumber}}
                </div>
    </ng-container>
 <ng-container>
```

Now show:

- test

  - A

    - 0002
  - A

    - 0012
  - B

    - 0502
- test 2

  - C

    - 08802
  - C

    - 7578
  - C

    - 06986802

I want to show:

- test

  - A

    - 0002
    - 0012
  - B

    - 0502
- test 2

  - C

    - 08802
    - 7578
    - 06986802

I was create a `pipe` to do that, but I have an error.

My pipe code:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'groupBy'
})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(collection: any[], property: string): any[] {
    if (!collection) {
      return null as any;
    }

    const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current) => {
      if (!previous[current[property]]) {
        previous[current[property]] = [current];
      } else {
        previous[current[property]].push(current);
      }

      return previous;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
  }
}
```

Error:

> .html:66:34 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'ItmesModel[] | u
> ndefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.   Type
> 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>
> 66               *ngFor="let item of d?.items | groupBy: 'category' ;
> index as j"
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    if (!collection) {
      return [];
    }
```

Comment: I have the same error